# Bash error - binary operator expected

Tags: bash, ubuntu, installation, pgi, pgi-accelerator

I am trying to install PGI Compilers 2016 and after running the `install` file
I get an error:

```
binary operator expected
```

on the line:

```
if test -d $DIR/install_components ; then
```

[ShellCheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) says "add double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting" whatever it means.

But the whole installation suite is quite big, so am I supposed to add quotes in zillion places or is there some command I may use to go around it?

Comment: If $DIR contains spaces, the command will fail, because the variable will be expanded into two arguments. If you know your $DIR will never contain a space, you can safely ignore that. The best would be to report the issue with the package maintainer

Comment: I'd be leery of running the installation script, because whoever wrote it didn't really know what they were doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$DIR` contains spaces, the command will fail, because the variable will be expanded into two arguments.

If you know your `$DIR` will never contain a space, you can safely ignore that. The best would be to report the issue with the package maintainer.

Note that this could do very harmful things to your computer, say your script somewhere does:

```
rm $DIR
```

and `$DIR="-rf /"`, then this would execute the famous `rm -rf /`